# How to vectorise this simple assignment loop in matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have a vector v of values and a vector r of indices. I want to store the values in a matrix m as follows:

```
for i = 1:length(v)
    m(i, r(i)) = v(i);
end
```

What is the fastest way to do this in a vectorized way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know if it is faster, I suppose so but the difference might be very small, but here is one way:

```
m(sub2ind(size(m),1:length(v),r(1:length(v))))=v;
```

If `r` is a column vector then `sub2ind` will complain about vectors size, you can just take its transpose and it will solve this.

Comment: If `r` and `v` are the same length, then `r(1:length(v))` simplifies to just `r`.